Expand Selection of Nearby faces by Level through Geometry Nodes
I'm trying to find a way to expand the selection of nearby faces within geometry nodes. For my case, I'm beginning with a select number of faces created from a Raycast node and increasing my selection outward with the faces nearby.

I would like to be able to control the selection of nearby faces by Level (Integer) rather than using 2 Evaluate on Domain nodes for each level of faces I expand to. Does someone know a handy way to do so?

Blender 4.1.1

This is the way since Blender 3.5:

Not screenshoting the result - it's the same as yours, since you were doing 3 float face-edge interpolations and I've set iterations to 3.

lol . I had spent an hour last night trouble shooting and blindly rummaging through the manual to find the node. I gave up and posted this question when I was worn out. I have to say that the Blur Attribute node is not one I use very often hence, why I couldn't come up with this solution. Many thanks!
